# doxygen syntax in python

Tags: python, doxygen

Can somebody please help me to figure out how to comment python code correctly to get parsed by doxygen?

Somehow it ignores the tags. The output (HTML) shows the tags:

```
@brief Creates a new Hello object.
This Hello Object is beeing used to ...

@param name The name of the user.
```

---

Both variants I tried do not work:

```
class Hello:
    """@brief short description...

    longer description
    """
    def __init__(self, name):
    """@brief Creates a new Hello object.

    This Hello Object is beeing used to ...

    @param name The name of the user.
    """
        self.name = name
```

---

```
class Hello:
    """\brief short description...

    longer description
    """
    def __init__(self, name):
    """\brief Creates a new Hello object.

    This Hello Object is beeing used to ...

    \param name The name of the user.
    """
        self.name = name
```

Comment: I presume your indentation is actually valid?

Comment: Yes it is. I just corrected it.

Comment: I am not allowed to choose the tool. I have to use doxygen. But I am not really familiar with it.

Comment: I read something about input-filters. I am using doxygen version 1.7.2 this should be able to parse python???

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Doxygen has also undocumented feature (or bug): It parses Doxygen syntax in docstring if you start docstring with an exclamation mark:

```
class Hello: 
    def __init__(self, name):
    """!@brief Creates a new Hello object.

    This Hello Object is being used to...

    @param name The name of the user.
    """
    self.name = name
        dosomething(12)

    def dosomething(x):         
        dosomethingelse
```

Note that in Python docsting, you need to use @ instead of \ to start Doxygen commands (backslash works as an escape character in docstring).

Answer (score 5):

For doxygen to recognize the special commands in Python comments you have to use the following comment form:

```
class Hello: 
    ## \brief Short description.
    # Longer description. 
    # \param self
    # \param name
    def __init__(self, name):         
        dosomething(12)

    def dosomething(x):         
        dosomethingelse
```

See http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#pythonblocks