# Characters in comment give error

Tags: python, string, documentation

At the top of my python script I have some documentation of the form

```
"""!
Documentation: \\storage1\gis\Nbig.docx
"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Hello world.")
```

When run it gives
`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 31-32: malformed \N character escape`

Why does this happen and how can it be prevented against? I would like to have the network path to the documentation in the comments. By the way, I found it from another example but what does the `!` do after `"""`?

Update: got it working. It seems LiClipse doesn't get affected bythe error, but running Python from the command line does.

Comment: you should escape backslashes `\ ` with double-backslashes `\\ `.

Comment: Although it is a comment, docstrings in python are treated as string literals, so they are still interpreted by the interpreter. You need to escape the backslashes to get it to work.

Comment: The exclamation mark `!` could be there because of parsing the docstring with  `doxygen` as described in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15535484/3991125)

Comment: @albert I thought I got it from here but evidently not.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387272/what-is-the-best-python-library-module-skeleton-code  Not sure where I got the `!` from but I'll start leaving it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using raw string format by prepending the string with `r`.

Example -

```
r"""!
Documentation: \\storage1\gis\Nbig.docx
"""
```

By prepending `r` we make sure that none of the `\` are treated as escape characters

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the \, so use \ instead of \ and \\ instead of \.
And the exclamation mark is a directive for the documentation tool Doxygen.